# How to set the default .NET framework for new projects in VS2013?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, project-settings

I'm working on a project that targets .net 4.0, It won't be changing to 4.5 in a hurry.

When I create a new project it defaults to .net 4.5. Is there anyway I can default it to 4.0 either globally at the Visual Studio level or (more preferably) at the solution level?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The easiest way is to just change the default .Net Framework version in the new project dialog.

- Go to File -> New Project
- At the top middle switch ".Net Framework 4.5" to ".Net Framework 4"
- Click the project you want

From that point on the "New Project" dialog will default to ".Net Framework 4"

Comment: So the answer for the 'or (more preferably) at the solution level' is *no*.