# Setting Default .NET Framework in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm running VS 2017 v15.4.4.

When I create a new project VS always defaults to using Framework v4.6.1, even though I have version 4.7 installed. I always have to manually change to version 4.7.

Is there any way to make VS *always* select version 4.7 for new projects (or even better yet, always use the most recent version of the .NET Framework available on my machine)?

Comment: have you tryed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21420971/2495004)?

Comment: @Albert: That doesn't work. It always goes back to 4.6.1 for the next new project.